# Write out SCSS code onto a page in Jekyll

Tags: angularjs, sass, jekyll

I've created a web page that's for all intents and purposes, a style guide for other developers working on our application.

I have my `.scss` files within the `_sass` directory in my Jekyll project, and it's created all the CSS files beautifully. On my page however I want to display the code from these `.scss` files in the page within some `<pre><code>` tags.

Currently I have the code in here repeated in both places. When it was quite small it wasn't such a problem, but now it's got bigger it needs *DRY*-ing out.

I first went down the path of using Jekyll's `{% include [path/to/file] %}`, and then realised that *only* works for stuff in the `_includes` folder, and I couldn't use the `include_relative` option either as the `_sass` folder isn't a child of the location it's used.

Secondly I tried using the angular approach, as I'm already using it in my application. Threw in some `<pre><code ng-include="'../_sass/components/_sflButton.scss'">` and expected it to work. Of course, it didn't because the `_sass` folder isn't generated into the actual site when you run it. And I can't seem to find a way of getting it to include it. Tried changing a few things in `_config.yml` to no avail.

So, *TL;DR*, I want to either be able to include the code from my `_sass` folder onto my page via Jekyll, or find a way of getting the `_sass` folder to be loaded into the generated site so I can load it in with Angular. Am I trying to do an impossible task here? Willing to listen to any suggestions that mean the code is only written in one place.

Answer (score 0):

The theory behind getting this done is as follows:

- `_sass` is a special directory for Jekyll (similar to `_layouts`, `_includes`) that is handled differently in comparison to other directories you create. Its contents are not output to the destination directory.
- you can write simple ruby programs and add them to a directory called `_plugins` and Jekyll will run those custom programs during the build process. (Ignored by GitHub Pages).
- Now write a ruby program to "read" the contents of `_sass` and have the resulting data be formatted as a hash and have this hash fed to existing `site_payload`
- The hash can be additionally passed as a `Drop` instance to have the data available via the `Liquid` templates.

I concede this answer doesn't actually solve your problem esp., if you're not familiar with Ruby, and Jekyll codebase. but it'll serve as a starting point..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I'm using Github pages, the solution you mention won't work for me :(.